# AudioKit v5 freeze after use Microphone, also in the cookbook

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, cookbook

It also happen cookbook:
start Tuner
then switch to DrumSequencer
after few time when switch quickly, the app freeze.
The App freeze happen after call engine.stop()
any idea what can solve this issue?

Comment: For me the app would freeze and pressing pause in the debugger would show execution stuck on `player.stop()` (player being an `AudioPlayer`). Using the debugger to poll if the engine was running showed that it was somehow stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved.
I pushed the fix to v5-develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

The AudioKit Cookbook is not intended to be a model for how any application should be set up, just a series of one-file examples to get you started. There is a GitHub Issues page for the Cookbook where things like this should be asked. Its a delicate balance to know what should be asked on the Issues page or on StackOverflow, but this one is pretty clear.

Comment: FWIW, I can at least confirm that the app does freeze, I just don't think this is the place to address it.

Comment: The problem also happen in my app, I just wanted to give an easy way to reproduce it. Where should I address this kind of problem, and do you happen to know how can I fix it?

Comment: You've described a symptom, but not really the problem, very specifically. The first step is to do better job at defining it. Is it just a matter of number of times the engine is stopped? If its speed, how slow does it have to be for it not not happen? etc

Comment: I'm describing a major problem in the Framework. I don't know what is the problem, all I know is that when I start the the engine with inputNode , then stop it, and start it once again with other Mixer configuration cause it to freeze.

Comment: Fixed by this: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/pull/2308 Good job @gilgul!